# Plotting a function (having different equations for different range of x) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function which is something like the one shown. i.e. for different range of x it has different forms(i don't know the mathematical term for such functions hence the detailed description)

[image]

First problem is i need to know how to plot these kind of functions in matlab.
Second problem is, The term 'h' has 3 different values, i need to plot three different functions for three different 'h' in the same graph

How can i do this in MATLAB. I am using syms to create the function definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the function in matlab so that it takes two arguments: x, and h (make sure to vectorize it with masks). Then choose over which interval you wan to display the function and sample your function over that interval, for each value of h. Finally gather all vectors in a matrix and plot the matrix.

Schematically:

```
function res = pbar(x, a, h)
  case1indices=find(x<0);
  case2indices=find(x>=0 && x<a);
  case3indices=find(x>=a);

  res(case1indices) = 0;
  res(case2indices) = 1/a*(1-exp(-x/h));
  res(case2indices) = ...
end
```

And then:

```
x = -10:.1:10
allres(:,1) = pbar(x, 2, 1)
allres(:,2) = pbar(x, 2, 2)
allres(:,3) = pbar(x, 2, 3)

plot(allres)
```

The above is most probably not correct (no access to Matlab to test right now) but hopefully useful.

Comment: You are designing a bar graph. I need a line graph, but i got your point, i'll try that. Thanks. But, initializing x=-10:.1:10 doesn't it mean that the plotting will be done between -10 to 10?

Comment: Yes indeed. One way or another, you will have to choose which interval you want to plot. An alternative is to use [fplot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply assume you have three functions f1, f2, f3 defined over the three intervals x1, x2, x3.

Calculate then  y1, y2, y3 ( y1=f1(x1)) , y2=f2(x2)) , y3=f3(x3)) .

Then join them i.e. x=(x1, x2, x3) and y=(y1, y2, y3).

Finally plot y vs x i.e. plot(x,y).

An alternative way is to plot (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)